# Unable to call the WebMethod using $.ajax to pass JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, vb.net, webmethod

I want to call the `webmethod` written in my VB Page. For that I've wrote the following code. But However it is directly going in **`error`** block and showing the message **`undefined`**.

### JavaScript

```
function fnSaveReview(){
   var content = new Object();
   content.TableName = "BAChildProjects"
   content.ColumnName = "cIsQCApproved"
   content.ColumnValue = "Y"
   content.Refcolumn = "vWorkSpaceId"
   content.RefValue = $('#<%= HProjectId.ClientId%>').val();
   var JsonString=JSON.stringify(content);

   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "frmBAProjectDefinition.aspx/UpdateFieldValues",
          data: JsonString,          
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
               alert('Data Reviewed Successfully.');          
          },
          failure: function(error) {
               alert(error);
          },
          error: function (data) {
               debugger ;
               alert(data.d);
          }
     });
}
```

### VB.NET

```
<Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function UpdateFieldValues(ByVal JSONString As String) As String

        Dim objhelpDb As New WS_HelpDbTable.WS_HelpDbTable
        Dim objLambda As New WS_Lambda.WS_Lambda
        Dim eStr As String = String.Empty
        Dim ds_Save As New DataSet
        Try

            ds_Save.Tables.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONString, GetType(System.Data.DataTable)))


            If Not objLambda.Save_UpdateFieldValues(WS_Lambda.DataObjOpenSaveModeEnum.DataObjOpenMode_Add, ds_Save, _
                                                 HttpContext.Current.Session(S_UserID), eStr) Then
                Return False
                Exit Function
            End If

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function
```

### Console.log(data);

```
Object {readyState: 4, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function (a){a=a||"abort",p&&p.abort(a),w(0,a);return this}
always: function (){return i.done.apply(i,arguments).fail.apply(i,arguments)}
complete: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
done: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
error: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
fail: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return s===2?n:null}
getResponseHeader: function (a){var c;if(s===2){if(!o){o={};while(c=bJ.exec(n))o[c[1].toLowerCase()]=c[2]}c=o[a.toLowerCase()]}return c===b?null:c}
isRejected: function (){return!!e}
isResolved: function (){return!!e}
overrideMimeType: function (a){s||(d.mimeType=a);return this}
pipe: function (a,b,c){return f.Deferred(function(d){f.each({done:[a,"resolve"],fail:[b,"reject"],progress:[c,"notify"]},function(a,b){var c=b[0],e=b[1],g;f.isFunction(c)?i[a](function(){g=c.apply(this,arguments),g&&f.isFunction(g.promise)?g.promise().then(d.resolve,d.reject,d.notify):d[e+"With"](this===i?d:this,[g])}):i[a](d[e])})}).promise()}
progress: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
promise: function (a){if(a==null)a=h;else for(var b in h)a[b]=h[b];return a}
readyState: 4
responseText: "<html>
↵    <head>
↵        <title>The resource cannot be found.</title>
↵        <style>
↵         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
↵         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
↵         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
↵         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
↵         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
↵         pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}
↵         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
↵         .version {color: gray;}
↵         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
↵         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
↵        </style>
↵    </head>
↵
↵    <body bgcolor="white">
↵
↵            <span><H1>Server Error in '/BizNET' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>
↵
↵            <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>
↵
↵            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">
↵
↵            <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
↵            <br><br>
↵
↵            <b> Requested URL: </b>/BizNET/frmBAProjectDefinition.aspx/UpdateFieldValues<br><br>
↵
↵            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>
↵
↵            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5420; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5459
↵
↵            </font>
↵
↵    </body>
↵</html>
↵<!-- 
↵[HttpException]: The file '/BizNET/frmBAProjectDefinition.aspx' does not exist.
↵   at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath)
↵   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
↵   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
↵   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
↵   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
↵   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
↵   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path)
↵   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
↵   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
↵-->"
setRequestHeader: function (a,b){if(!s){var c=a.toLowerCase();a=m[c]=m[c]||a,l[a]=b}return this}
state: function (){return e}
status: 404
statusCode: function (a){if(a){var b;if(s<2)for(b in a)j[b]=[j[b],a[b]];else b=a[v.status],v.then(b,b)}return this}
statusText: "Not Found"
success: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
then: function (a,b,c){i.done(a).fail(b).progress(c);return this}
__proto__: Object
undefined
```

My main problem is debugger is not even going to the `WebMethod` of `VB.NET`

Comment: do a `console.log(data);` in error callback and post here..

Comment: Please check it out. I've posted the log of data in `error` block.

Comment: @iJay - alert message in **error** shows the message *undefined*

Comment: If you see your log, there is no response from server. 

"<span><H1>Server Error in '/BizNET' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>
<h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>" you have call correct file or fix the error in your vb page

Comment: @Bala: If you have seen, I've called the correct `web method` of VB page in `JavaScript` portion. Even arguments are also the same. 

What else correction would be required?

Comment: I clearly explains its a 404 error, means page cannot be found or resource unavailable. vb.net code directly by calling it through fiddler or firefox poster to confirm are you calling correct page.

Answer (score 0):

This is an anonymous issue, I've too spent lot of time on this issue. I can resolve this issue the following manner.

Type I

1. Clear the solution (Build -> Clear Solution)
2. and then rebuild the solution (Build -> Rebuild Solution)

Type II

1. Close the entire solution (File -> Exit)
2. and then reopen your solution.

By the above steps, you can fix that issue.